# cloud-based build for debian packages with network access?

Tags: continuous-integration, package, debian, cloud

I have some debian packages, which need network access in build time
- one builds with maven, and needs to access the repositories
- the other tries to bind to 127.0.0.1 as part of some unit tests

I would use launchpad for these, but the launchpad buildd does not support any of these kinds of network operations.
I am also building the packages with travis, so I would upload only the binary packages to launchpad, but it is also unsupported.

I am looking for either a cloud based debian package builder with network access,
or a cloud-based debian package repository where I can upload my binary and source packages.

Is there any?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can use Jenkins as a Continuous Integration tool. CloudBees offers Jenkins as Service, where you can just test the environment you want to see if it meets your needs or not.

Since their slaves run on a Fedora Linux machine, you can easily generate the .deb files and after that use a Debian Repository as a Service. [Bintray](https://bintray.com/), for example, lets you upload your .deb packages on the cloud. Bintray is a part of JFrog, so you can easily enable the [JFrog](http://www.cloudbees.com/platform-service-jfrog.cb) service through this PaaS.

You can upload your .deb package from the command line using this command:

curl -T  -uXXXXXXXXX: https://api.bintray.com/content/XXXXXXXXX/deb///

So my idea is that you could use the Jenkins instance in order to create your .deb package (build + tests), and then upload your .deb package to Bintray using the Command Line from a Post build step on your Jenkins job.

Once you have your .deb package on Bintray you can easily access to the artifactory to get .deb for your builds/tests...

Answer (score 0):

The solution was the following:
For the one which needs network socket for testing:
- I build with travis and do the testing there. I post the source packages to launchpad from that build. Testing is turned off in debian/rules. This way the package builds for more ubuntu revisions simultaneosly.

For the mavis one maybe bintray would be the right answer. Now I build with drone.io, and post to sourceforge FRS, but no apt repo there.